# how to pass data from angular to rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I'am very new to angular, only a week old. My question is how do i pass data from angular to rails? As you can see i only need to save whatever is been input it in {{entry.name}} into rails. Thank you

```
          <fieldset>
               <div class="row" ng-controller="tagForm">
                 <fieldset >
                 <div ng-click="addEntry()">
                  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-10 ">
                     <%= f.text_field :description,:placeholder => 'What are your area of expertise',:'ng-model'=> "newEntry.name", :class => 'form-control border' %>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2 center form-button" >

                   <input type="button" value="Add" class="btn btn-orange btn-add" >
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-offset-2" id="up" ><br/>
                     <span class="label label-primary" ng-repeat="entry in entries">{{entry.name}}</span>
                  </div>
                  </div>
                  </fieldset>
```

Comment: time to read up on `$http` and AJAX in general

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to communicate with external server. you should user `$http` or `$resource` depending on the architecture of your server her are the docs for them as starting point https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http and https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource